# What UK aircraft looks like an Islander but with twin fins?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

Driving on the [M40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M40_motorway) recently just south of Banbury, England, I saw a distinctive smallish plane I'm trying to identify — probably military from the dull grey/green color.

It looked a lot like the [Islander](http://aircraftrecognition.co.uk/islander.html), but:

- It had a tailplane and twin fins
- The tail boom was narrower in proportion to the body<s>, and more distinct from the body than the Islander's is</s> *(I think I'm misremembering or mis-saw that part — I **was** driving on the motorway, after all)*
- The body may well have been a bit bulkier (or that may have been an illusion caused by the narrowness of the tail boom)
- The wings had a normal-looking span for the size of the aircraft but were shorter front-to-back than seemed normal (to my very-much-not-expert eye)

Like the Islander it was a twin prop with a fairly pointy nose.

Does anyone have any idea what it was?

Comment: Could it be a [Short Skyvan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_SC.7_Skyvan)?

Comment: Or possibly a [Short Sherpa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_C-23_Sherpa)?

Comment: @Monolo: Thanks. It looked a lot like that, but there was a distinct tail boom, rather than the body extending back to the tailplane.

Comment: @fooot: Thanks. More similar to the Skyvan, I'd've said, but see the note above to Monolo.

Comment: [This list contains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_active_United_Kingdom_military_aircraft) all aircraft which UK military is using. Can you spot yours in there?

Comment: @Farhan: Sadly, no. Thanks for the link. We do get historic craft flown around here periodically, so it may be something that *used* to be used...

Comment: There are US airbases in the UK as well.

Comment: What about a Flying Boxcar? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_C-119_Flying_Boxcar

Comment: @GdD: Thanks! But much smaller than that, with just the one tailboom.

Comment: I'm thinking I may just delete this. It's one thing to say "What's this aircraft" and produce a picture of the one in question, but a picture of one vaguely like it and a description of the differences may be a bit too much of an ask. :-) I do really appreciate everyone's attempts to find it, though!!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I think it's a good question. Certainly well detailed with more information than some other ID questions on here

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can you provide the image source for the picture in your question?

Comment: @SentryRaven: I don't recall where I got it. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds an awful lot like a [C-145](http://www.af.mil/AboutUs/FactSheets/Display/tabid/224/Article/467765/c-145a.aspx), or maybe the 'civilian' version (it's primarily used by militaries), the  [PZL Skytruck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PZL_M28_Skytruck).

[image: C-145]
<sup>[Source](http://www.919sow.afrc.af.mil/photos/mediagallery.asp?galleryID=10788&page=2)</sup>

It's used by the U.S. Air Force, so seeing it in Britain would not be surprising - all 3 of the U.S. Air Force's RAF joint use bases are within 100 air miles.

- It's twin-engine, with a tailplane and twin fins
- Its tail boom does narrow somewhat and distinguish itself, as seen [here](http://th06.deviantart.net/fs70/200H/f/2013/008/b/a/dat_skytruck_ass_by_indeepschit-d5qvbna.jpg)
- It does have somewhat of a chunky body
- The wings are fairly [thin](http://www.americanspecialops.com/images/aircraft/skytruck.jpg) (front-to-back)

Comment: That **has** to be it, thank you! Goes to prove what memory is like (and seeing something only in glances -- I *was* driving on the motorway, after all). I could have sworn the tailboom was more distinct from the body, but looking at the pictures, this is the plane.

Comment: @SSumner Can you provide the image source for the picture in your answer?

Comment: @sentryraven - done